# Запретить определенный вызов метода объекта несколько раз

Tags: ооп, javascript

```
function create_menu(){
    if(typeof create_menu.flag==='object'){
        return create_menu.flag;
        }
    create_menu.flag=this

    function create_skeleton(num,value_li,class_ul){
        ....
        }

        this.create_ul=function(num,text,class_ul){
        create_skeleton(num,text,class_ul);
            return this;

            }
        this.add_class_li=function(number_li,class_li){
        ....    
            return this
        }
    }
```

Есть конструктор.Хочу создать объект в котором нельзя вызвать метод create_ul() несколько раз.
Вроде помогает вот такая штука,но не  для не синглентона.

```
this.create_ul=function(num,text,class_ul){
            if(!create_menu.flag2){
            create_skeleton(num,text,class_ul);
            create_menu.flag2=true
            }
            return this;

            }
```

Интересует другие решения

Comment: ооп и javasсript писать в одном предложение нельзя.

Comment: странное утверждение

Comment: @shurik, скорее всего, вы просто не асилили :)

Когда-то я тоже так думал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То же самое, но используя замыкание:

```
var singleCallFunc = (function(){
    var flag = false,
        result;    
    return function(){
        if(flag) {
            return result;
        }
        else {
            return flag = true, result = computeResult();
        }    
    }    
}());
```

примерно так же работает [_.once()](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-64) из [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#once)

Comment: Да спасибо.А как заставить ее поддерживать цепочку вызовов?Или никак?
Я так понимаю нужно return this возвратить но не помогает

Comment: скорее всего в this у вас window

Comment: та нет вроде делаю через self

Answer (score 3):

```
function func() {
  // do some work
  console.log('calling');
  var result = 'workResult';
  func = function(){
    console.log('just return result');
    return result;
  }
  return result;
}

func(); // -> calling
func(); // -> just return result
```

Если нужно что-бы функция, после вызова, ничего не возвращала и ничего не делала, просто перезаписываем ее на пустую.